# Why is web text distorted?

Tags: windows-7, browser, web

On various websites text is distorted, this is happening in both Chrome and IE, but only to certain parts of text - the same page can show both normal and distorted text. See the two screenshots below. I am running Windows 7 64-bit, and AMD Catalyst drivers. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to disable Hardware acceleration in both browsers.

Comment: Ive disabled `GPU compositing on all pages` in Chrome with no effect

Comment: open Catalyst Center and play with the offered AA settings.

Comment: I couldn't find anything that had any effect.

Comment: weird font, is it a font problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that this is a font problem.

A first step toward analyzing the problem is finding out exactly which font is used for
the distorted text and how it differs from non-distorted ones. It would also be interesting to know if the problem arrives in Firefox.

Some tools you can use are :

Firefox : The add-on [Font Finder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/) that can analyze the font, and [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)
that can in addition list all the CSS styles that are affecting the text.

Chrome : [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or the extension [WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm) or [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

IE : Developer tools (F12) or [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Please post your results of the analysis of the problematic fonts, even if not conclusive.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. The font stack `'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;` was causing the problem. I deleted Helvetica Neue out of the fonts directory and everything is now OK!

Comment: Actually only the Ultralight version was in the pack, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a guess, but I'd suggest tweaking your cleartype settings - this should be under adjust cleartype text in windows. Since this turns up in screenshots, this probably rules out monitor related wierdness, its probably some setting somewhere, and cleartype seems the most obvious to me.